# Windows 7 Update: 1 out of 30 never completes

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates

For the past two days, whenever I want to shut down my laptop, there is the little yellow arrow indicating that while shutting down, Windows 7 will configure/install new updates. No problem, right? Just click shut down, the updates will install and life will go on as usual. Wrong. The update has been stuck at 1 out of 30... and no matter how long I leave it, it never completes and shuts down.

I have been shutting it down manually (by holding down the power button) and whenever I turn it on and want to shut down the update is still there. Any ideas of how to either get it complete or get rid of it?

Comment: How long did you leave it to try?  If one of them happens to be Service Pack 1, it could take a while to apply.  If you open the Windows Update Panel can you determine which updates are waiting to apply?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your `Windows Update` under Start -> All Programs.
2. Look at your Update-History. There should be one Update failing each time. Double click it.
3. In that window that pops up, there is a link that looks like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/*anyKbNumber*. Click that link.
4. The download-page for this update opens. Download it and install it manually (don't forget to right-click it and choose "Run as Administrator")

Manually installing an update is often the solution for stucking updates.
If that update is Win 7 SP1 you SHOULD install it manually to prevent breaking your system if you have had problems with it (SP1 crashed a few PCs over here).

If manually installing that update doesn't work, tell us your error-description (if any).

Comment: Manually installing a bugging update is indeed usually the fix.  (Sometimes clearing the update cache helps too if you're having systematic problems, but it sounds like this is getting stuck on a particular update.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the manual installation. Also, I have also found that the updates won't configure if you're not online during the process. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-update